# Propensity Score Matching: Can I use this test to compare the coping strategies for health shock between Vietnam and India compared to comparison test

Tags: propensity-scores

I want to investigate the coping strategies employed by households during health shock in Vietnam and India. In place of regular chi square or independent sample t test, I want to use PSM by controlling and matching the covariates. Is it possible? Because most of the literature and articles only use it to compare control and treatment group.

Comment: Maybe you can try survey weights? https://epirhandbook.com/en/survey-analysis.html#weighted-proportions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.Propensity Score Matching is made to reduce biased between control and treatment group according to your covariates to remove the confounding effect. After matching, you then can now proceed to using the resulting propensity score which summarises the covariates or their distribution as a means to adjust for any possible biased from the confounding variables.

After PSM result, you can now compare your "Treatment" (Coping strategies) without worry of any confounding effect.

It is a supposed more simpler alternative to doing regression analysis to control for any interaction from the covariates.

Comment: Hi Darf! thank you for your comment. However, I am little worried as in my case there is no treatment or control group. It just comparing data from 2 different countries. Is it okay?

Comment: oh sorry. I may have mixed up what's the "Treatment" and the "Outcome" in your study.